# What's the difference between these two volume bars in Android Marshmallow?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, volume-control, volume

What's the difference between the top volume bar (squiggle) and bottom volume bar (bell)?

[image: Volume bars]

I think they both have something to do with notification volume, and most of the time changing one also changes the other. I am running Cyanogenmod 13 (but I don't think it is a Cyanogenmod-specific feature).

Comment: Are you using a theme? Can you revert to stock theme and then post a screenshot? Stock Android 6 doesn't show four bars and CM13 doesn't show that squiggle. Instead, it shows the ringer volume. What does Settings -> Sounds gives? I think you have notification and ringtone volumes linked as well.

Comment: I was using blakZent theme, after reverting to the stock theme the top bar shows a ringing phone instead of a squiggle, which makes things much clearer. You're right, in Settings -> Sounds, there is a toggle 'Link ringtone & notification volumes', which I had switched on. Thanks!

Comment: I think one is ringer or notifications, the other (music note) is probably media volume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears from the screenshot that a theme is in place with its own set of icons. Stock Android Marshmallow doesn't show four but only three bars. The extra one CM shows is for notification volume. Anyhow, a theme alters the icon but not the order of bars. You can always revert to stock theme or icons and get this result:

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

- First bar      : Ringer volume
- Second bar : Media volume
- Third bar     : Alarm volume
- Fourth bar   : Notification volume

If you don't intend to revert the theme icons, then head over to Settings app → Sounds and behold the meaning of icons yourself:

[image: IMG:]